# Can VB.NET-specific warnings be suppressed by <SupressMessage>?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, suppress-warnings

**I would like to suppress some of [these VB.NET warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y20cc1z.aspx) at class level. (=Not globally.)** Supression is intended as temporary woarkaround until the code of some classes gets properly cleaned. There are hundreds of **ID: 42016 (*Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'TypeA' to 'TypeB'.*)** warnings in legacy code, I cannot afford to fix them all right now.

I found that **[SuppressMessage attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)** can be effectively used for the task but I cannot find proper argument values to supply to `<SuppressMessage()>` for **warning 42016**.

**My question is:** can be warning 42016 and other above referenced VB.NET-specific warnings suppressed by `SuppressMessage` attribute?

If you know there is no way of doing it, I will accept it as the answer, too.

*Note: I know how to suppress them globally, this is not an option at the moment.*

Comment: Isn't this an `error` and not a `warning`?

Comment: Yes, it is an error. I thought it merely has status of warning but probably I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that does not get you anywhere.  SuppressMessageAttribute is only used by code analysis (aka FxCop), the VB.NET compiler ignores it.  And it is not a warning, it is a compile error.  You can never ignore an error.

`Option Strict` can only be changed at file scope, there is no support for changing it on-the-fly.  The only reasonable approach here is to tackle the borken source code one .vb file at a time.  Not an unreasonable approach.

Comment: A minor addition: if one file contains multiple classes, it may be worth moving each class into its own file, so that for those classes that still need `Option Strict Off`, no other classes get that with them.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Hans. Yes I'm adding `Option Strict On` to files one by one. Some of them still pop 100+ errors. I originally thought that `Option Strict On` can be configured to work partially (catch only some types of problems), but now I see it cannot.

Comment: @hvd - sure, in most cases classes are already laid this way. But some classes still contain too many problematic expressions. But thanks, maybe your comment will help someone.